# Use of "issued" vs. "was issued"

Tags: word-usage

I've been casually reading a number of legal texts lately, and all of them use "issued" like this: "The order issued the next day." or "The government ceased to apply that provision after the order issued."

However, in everyday language, I would use "issued" like this: "the order was issued the next day."

So, which is correct? Both?

Thanks

Comment: Both, in context. Lawyers talk and write differently from other English speakers. This use of _issue_ is an application of the Middle Alternation, which normally doesn't apply  to _issue_. But it's used as shorthand and tribespeak by lawyers.